# Most effective way to import large images?

Tags: css

I am interested in adding a landsacpe footer on my website but the image size is 115KB and will load on every page... Is there any effective way to load an huge image such as this one:

`http://gyazo.com/5b1b7312ec4370873368df0181e41b13.png`

Comment: Browsers cache images after they are first loaded

Comment: So it's not really a huge issue if you have a huge image on your website?

Comment: It will slow down an initial page load and piss off your mobile visitors but otherwise it isn't a big deal

Comment: Only the first time (and you still need to be prepared for users cursing you for it), and with reasonable browser cache settings. Try the same image saved as JPEG. This particular one is not entirely suitable for that, but possibly a high quality setting distorts not too much, and might still make it smaller.

Comment: .. Saving it as GIF with Photoshop takes it down from 139Kb to around 100Kb. Didn't try JPEG, though, since this needs an appreciation of "still of reasonable quality".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a few things that may help you:

EDIT: I tried the second tip in the list below  (tinypng.com) and it reduced the size of your image with 71% to 39.1 KB. So that's a big win.

1. Make sure to set the cache headers on your webserver so that the browser can cache the file. Also use the same URL for all other times you use the image. Doing these two simple things will make sure that the image will only get downloaded the first time the browser requests it. All other times it will be loaded from the browser's cache.
2. Make sure to check if the image is as small as it can be. If you use a PNG then use tools like https://tinypng.com/ to squash all metadata out of the image. If you use a JPEG then maybe lower its quality. If you use Photoshop make sure to "save the image for web". This will also reduce the size. For photographs you are mostly better of using JPEGs, for text or other images that need to be lossless use PNG or GIF.
3. Loading images will not really slow down your page that much. Not like JavaScript anyway. Loading Javascript will block the rendering of the page until the JS file is downloaded unless you use special loading techniques. That is not the case for images: the page will continue being rendered and the user can start using the page.
4. If the image is placed using an IMG tag the make sure to set the width and the height of the image in the CSS (or using the img width and height attributes). That will make sure that the browser does not need to reflow the page when the image is downloaded. It will know what size it needs to be even before the image is downloaded.
5. There is a maximum number of parallel requests per domain that the browser will do. If the image has a very low priority you could postpone its loading and wait for the onLoad event. This will make sure the other resources (with a a higher prio) will be downloaded first. This will require some JavaScript, but not that much (Use an image lazy loader, there are many).
6. As I said in the previous item the are a maximum number of requests PER DOMAIN. This is why you could also create a new (sub)domain and load some content from there. It will increase the total number of resources that will be downloaded in parallel. using a CDN will also help here because they also have a separate domain (and they are optimised as well).
7. If you want to read some REALLY GOOD books about this kind of optimising, read these: 
   [http://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-Web-Sites-Essential/dp/0596529309](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529309)
   [http://www.amazon.com/Even-Faster-Web-Sites-Performance/dp/0596522304](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596522304)